# Can not open .mpp file in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, ms-project

My question has two part to it:

1. I can't open MPP files in my computer. My understanding is I don't have MS Project in my computer, but I can't find the proper file format; for example xml from my computer. How can I open this file at all?
2. I checked in a different computer. I can access the file on read-only mode and  when downloading the document I can modify it. What can be the reason and how can I work online without READ ONLY mode?

Answer (score 3):

1. You can't open a file without the software, so you need MS Project. If you want to actually sync an MPP file with a Sharepoint task list, you need MS Project Pro.
2. You probably have read only permissions over the mpp, if you want to be able to modify it ask the owner of the site for contribute permissions.

Comment: I am the Owner of the site, but still have not permission to modify the .mpp file. Does it say that I need MS Project Pro? Is that only solution? If I am using currently MS Project Standard do I need to move to MS Project Pro?

Comment: You should be able to, check with the site collection administration if you have full access over the site, as you tried in another computer and you were not able to do so I'm assuming it's permissions issues. You need Project Pro only if you are trying to sync over the mpp file with a list, if you are just opening the mpp file and you have normal Project it should not be an issue.